# Making transformers BertForSequenceClassification initial layers non-trainable for pytorch training

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to do a transfer learning with BertForSequenceClassification https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#bertforsequenceclassification

This is my simple NN model for classification.

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForSequenceClassification
class NN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NN, self).__init__()
        self.bert = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels = 17)
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.bert(x)

a = NN()
```

Once I print my model I get this:

```
NN(
  (bert): BertForSequenceClassification(
    (bert): BertModel(
      (embeddings): BertEmbeddings(
        (word_embeddings): Embedding(30522, 768, padding_idx=0)
        (position_embeddings): Embedding(512, 768)
        (token_type_embeddings): Embedding(2, 768)
        (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
        (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
      )
      (encoder): BertEncoder(
        (layer): ModuleList(
          (0): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (1): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (2): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (3): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (4): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (5): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (6): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (7): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (8): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (9): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (10): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
          (11): BertLayer(
            (attention): BertAttention(
              (self): BertSelfAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
              (output): BertSelfOutput(
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
              )
            )
            (intermediate): BertIntermediate(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
            )
            (output): BertOutput(
              (dense): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
              (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
            )
          )
        )
      )
      (pooler): BertPooler(
        (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
        (activation): Tanh()
      )
    )
    (dropout): Dropout(p=0.1, inplace=False)
    (classifier): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=17, bias=True)
  )
)
```

I want to make only the last Linear layer trainable but I can't access the layers of my model. I have tried iterating model as a list and features but both gives error that there is no such attribute.

```
a.features
```

How can make all my layers frozen except the last linear layer?

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation says,

> class transformers.BertForSequenceClassification(config)[source]
>
> ```
> Bert Model transformer with a sequence classification/regression head on top (a linear layer on top of the pooled output) e.g. for GLUE tasks. This model is a PyTorch torch.nn.Module sub-class. Use it as a regular PyTorch Module and refer to the PyTorch documentation for all matters related to general usage and behavior.
> ```

So, you can treat your bert layer as an nn.Module container and use these attributes and functions https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html

You can use `list(a.parameters())` to get the layers and use requires_grad to make layers trainable or non-trainable.

```
for pp in a.parameters():
    pp.requires_grad = False

list(a.parameters())[-1].requires_grad = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
for param in self.bert.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.